# How to get notified when camera, contacts etc is accessed by another app, perhaps in background?

Tags: android

What I want is to monitor some resources on my phone. Like if some app access camera or mic in background on its own and not because of user I would like to get a notification.

Well, I seriously haven't started anything on this one so no code yet. I am working on app which is right now just other stuff and not this particular functionality. I have no idea how I should start with this.
A link to some example or some example here would be useful. 
I am open for any suggestion on what I want to achieve and how it is not good idea, if it is not.

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK for what you are seeking, in general.

Answer (score -1):

I think to monitor your device entirely you would need **root priviliges** on your phone. Then you can just simply monitor your processes and display info or do some action when something is happening with your hardware.

In your monitor app you use commands like:

```
Process process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/");
```

But if you can simply monitor your device while connected to computer - use **logcat**.